# Can I create a same pair in different DEXes?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, decentralized-applications

All.
I'm new to blockchain and currently in a course of learning it.
While I was reading books about DEX(Decentralized Exchanges), I have got a questions regarding liquidity and pair.

***Is it possible to create the same pair on difference DEXes?***

Meaning, if I have just created a token called "MYT", can I create ETH/MYT on Uniswap and Sushiswap at the same time?

If then, how can I keep the same rate across these 2 platforms?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to create the same pair on difference DEXes?*

Yes. You just execute the proper functions to create a pair on the multiple selected DEX contracts.

> *how can I keep the same rate across these 2 platforms?*

A common way is to run an arbitrage bot. It buys (increasing the price) or sells (decreasing the price) on one platform until the price on this platform matches the other one. This can be expanded to automatically control the price on multiple platforms.